# Error creating bean with name,Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field,Initialization of bean failed;

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, spring-mvc, tomcat

I get some errors from TomCat Please help..

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: **Error creating bean with name 'userController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userService'**; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>        **Error creating bean with name 'userServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userDao'**; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
>       **Error creating bean with name 'userDAO': Initialization of bean failed;** nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError

My UserDAO

```
package dao;

import entities.User;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface UserDAO extends CrudRepository<User, Integer> {
}
```

My userserviceImpl

```
package service.impl;

import beans.UserBean;
import dao.UserDAO;
import entities.User;
import service.EntityBeanConverter;
import service.UserService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;


import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@Service
@Transactional
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserDAO userDao;

    @Autowired
    private EntityBeanConverter converter;

    @Override
    public Iterable<UserBean> getAllUsers() {
        Iterable<User> users = userDao.findAll();
        List<UserBean> beanList = converter.convertToBeanList(users, UserBean.class);

        return beanList;
    }

    @Override
    public UserBean getUserById(Integer userId) {
        Optional<User> user = userDao.findById(userId);
        UserBean bean = converter.convertToBean(user, UserBean.class);

        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public void saveUser(UserBean user) {
        User userEntity = converter.convertToEntity(user, User.class);
        userDao.save(userEntity);
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteUser(Integer userId) {
        userDao.deleteById(userId);
    }
}
```

My userController

```
package controller;

import beans.UserBean;
import service.UserService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping("/users.html")
    public ModelAndView showUsersPage() {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("users");
        return modelAndView;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/update-user.html")
    public ModelAndView updateUser(@RequestParam(name = "user_id") Integer userId) {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("users");

        UserBean user = userService.getUserById(userId);
        modelAndView.addObject("user", user);

        return modelAndView;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/delete-user.html")
    public ModelAndView deleteUser(@RequestParam(name = "user_id") Integer userId) {
        userService.deleteUser(userId);

        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("redirect:users.html");
        return modelAndView;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/save-user.html", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView saveUser(UserBean user) {
        userService.saveUser(user);

        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("redirect:users.html");
        return modelAndView;
    }

    @ModelAttribute(name = "userList")
    private Iterable<UserBean> getUserList() {
        Iterable<UserBean> userList = userService.getAllUsers();
        return userList;
    }

    @ModelAttribute(name = "user")
    private UserBean getEmptyUser() {
        return new UserBean();
    }
}
```

I don't know where to find my errors problem, maybe someone help me!

Comment: Your DAO class references entity.User but it is not included in your post.  Reading through the stack trace, Unsatisfied dependency takes you to each preceeding layer.  In this case ending up at UserDao cant be initialized.  The dependency here is on the User object. I think you likely are missing some Hibernate annotations or have a type problem(integer/Integer) or something similar in your User object class..

Comment: I want to see which package you set for `component-scan` ?

Comment: https://github.com/h4x00rs/First-CRUD-Project.git
User object in module-entities, 
component-scan in module-dao & service(applicationContext files)

Comment: @H4X00RS, What did u do about it?